# Why is vtable pointer aligned to 8 bytes on x86 compiled program?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, memory-management, windbg, memory-alignment

I have the following structure in a piece of code (compiled on x86):

```
0:012> dt prog!_TESTSTRUCT
   +0x000 __VFN_table : Ptr32 
   +0x008 szAddr           : Ptr32 Wchar
   +0x00c szOpCode         : Ptr32 Wchar
   +0x010 szMnemonic       : Ptr32 Wchar
   +0x014 szArgs           : Ptr32 Wchar
   +0x018 addr             : Uint8B
   +0x020 nextOffset       : Uint8B
```

As you can see, the vtable ptr, though 4 bytes in size is aligned to 8 bytes.

For reference, here is another structure from the same piece of code, that is normally aligned:

```
0:012> dt prog!_TESTSTRUCT2
   +0x000 __VFN_table : Ptr32 
   +0x004 pClient          : Ptr32 IDebugClient5
   +0x008 pDebugControl    : Ptr32 IDebugControl4
   +0x00c pDebugSystemObjects : Ptr32 IDebugSystemObjects
   +0x010 pDebugDataSpaces : Ptr32 IDebugDataSpaces
   +0x014 pDebugSymbols    : Ptr32 IDebugSymbols3
   +0x018 handlesAcquired  : Bool
```

Why is a 32bit ptr on x86 aligned to 8 bytes in the first structure? What am I missing here?

**EDIT 1:**

```
class _TESTSTRUCT   size(40):
1>      +---
1>   0  | {vfptr}
1>   8  | szAddr
1>  12  | szOpCode
1>  16  | szMnemonic
1>  20  | szArgs
1>  24  | addr
1>  32  | nextOffset
1>      +---
1>  
1>  _TESTSTRUCT::$vftable@:
1>      | &_TESTSTRUCT_meta
1>      |  0
1>   0  | &_TESTSTRUCT::{dtor}
1>  
1>  _TESTSTRUCT::{dtor} this adjustor: 0
1>  _TESTSTRUCT::__delDtor this adjustor: 0
1>  _TESTSTRUCT::__vecDelDtor this adjustor: 0

class _TESTSTRUCT2  size(28):
1>      +---
1>   0  | {vfptr}
1>   4  | pDebugClient
1>   8  | pDebugControl
1>  12  | pDebugSystemObjects
1>  16  | pDebugDataSpaces
1>  20  | pDebugSymbols
1>  24  | handlesAcquired
1>      | <alignment member> (size=3)
1>      +---
1>  
1>  _TESTSTRUCT2::$vftable@:
1>      | &_TESTSTRUCT2_meta
1>      |  0
1>   0  | &_TESTSTRUCT2::{dtor}
1>  
1>  _TESTSTRUCT2::{dtor} this adjustor: 0
1>  _TESTSTRUCT2::__delDtor this adjustor: 0
1>  _TESTSTRUCT2::__vecDelDtor this adjustor: 0
```

Comment: Well, nothing is being inherited from it so far really, it only had a virtual destructor which caused the vtable to be created. Otherwise it's a bare bone structure. And even if it was storing more than one pointer, isn't that supposed to show up when windbg parsed the structure? It clearly just shows that one 32bit pointer and then the 1st element of the structure itself.

Comment: Neither is this structure inherited from another.

Comment: Don't make us guess.  Use the `/d1reportAllClassLayout` compile option and post what you see.

Comment: Pretty handy flag, is the pasted info enough? or do I need to add more context etc from the output?

Comment: I think this explains it:

http://lolengine.net/blog/2012/10/21/the-stolen-bytes

As per the blog the issue seems to be VS specific. The presence of 8 byte long members in the structure are causing the compiler to misalign the 4 byte vfptr (even though its not showing padding in the structure layout ..weird). Do correct me if I am wrong though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained here

http://lolengine.net/blog/2012/10/21/the-stolen-bytes

The 8 byte structure member causes the vfptr to be misaligned to 8 bytes rather than 4 bytes, as vfptr is added to structure after all the other members have been added/aligned. This behavior seems to be Visual Studio specific